# Adding only date into core data as NSDate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a web service that returns a JSON object. The response consists of a refreshTime in UNIX timestamp (milliseconds) format. I convert the UNIX time stamp to NSDate by the following code:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[timeInUNIX objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue]/1000];
```

This gives me a time in the format

```
2009-11-13 19:47:49 +0000
```

I am only interested in the date object here. This is important since the day is used in NSSortDescriptor and also as section header in tableview and hence I separate the date and time with the following code:

```
+ (NSDate *)dateWithOutTime:(NSDate *)datDate {
    if( datDate == nil ) {
        datDate = [NSDate date];
    }
    NSDateComponents* comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:datDate];
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
}
```

The problem here is the returned NSDate object still contains a junk time value. Is there any way to store only the date in NSDate format?

Can someone help me with this?

Regards,
iSee

Comment: I'd change this method to reside in a category on NSDate. Calling it lie `[myDate dateWithOutTime];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSDate has to have a time - it is a number of seconds since a reference date, it represents a specific point in time.

If you are only interested in the day/month/year sections, the correct way to deal with this is to use a date formatter or date components when presenting the date, rather then when you store it. Alternatively, store the date as a string, but this way you lose any date functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible solutions, both not very pretty:

1. Take the NSTimeInterval from the date, then truncate it down to the nearest 60*60*24 (seconds*minutes*hours). Something like interval = floor(interval - interval % (60*60*24)). Create a new date from that.
2. Convert the date into a string showing only the date, then convert that string back to NSDate (might still have junk time components, though, but you can pad the string with 0 values).

Comment: Converting it to NSString is the only option but I will not be able to sort according to the the date in NSFetchController...

Comment: In order to sort a date as String field, store it in this format: YYYYMMDD